# Make Less Water Come From an Inflow Blender

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

How can I make an *Inflow* release less water? I looked at the *Inflow* settings and there is nothing. What settings in the *Domain* (I would assume it is the *Domain*) would make it look like there is less water coming out of the *Inflow* object? I want there to still be the same amount of frames, have the water travels just as far (I can't just slow down the time), and have everything else look the same.

Comment: with "Unity" in the title , is the simulation done in blender or in unity?

Comment: I'm sorry I was just working in Unity. It's in Blender

Answer (score 3):

Lower the velocity you have set in the sources fluid settings. The velocity changes how fast water flows out of it. Also, scaling down the object can change the size f the stream that comes out.

Comment: does the number of vertices/faces contribute to the amount of water?

Comment: That seems to help but then the water simply falls off of the inflow. Is there a way to give it more starting velocity while still keeping the amount of water outputted the same?

Comment: @DylanSiegler The only way (I know of) to change water output on an inflow is scaling the source object or changing velocity values. You can only change how much water comes out of it at once (The size, or scale of the object) and how fast that water comes out (Velocity)

Comment: @R00t I think its more the mass or volume of the object than the amount of vertices on that object.